# How to listen selection change of dropdown and set the default selected value using ember2.0?

Tags: ember.js

I have created the dropdown of country name and set country code as a value for each option .I want to set the default country name and also  listen the selection change of the dropdown .I have tried the following code

**HTML**

```
<select class="left-float" onchange={{action selectionchange}} >
  {{#each model.countries as |country|}}
   <option value="{{country.code}}" selected={{eq country.code "IN"}} >{{country.name}}</option>
 {{/each}}
</select>
```

**Router**

```
App.SignupRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function () {            
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
        countries: Countries
    });
},
actions:{
selectionchange:function(value){

}
}
});
```

Could please help me to resolve this

Comment: Is `selectionchange` being called when you change the dropdown?  Also, it should probably be on the component, not the route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Sindhu,

Another simple solution would be to create a custom helper `eq`. The custom helper would look like:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export function eq(params) {
  return params[0] === params[1];
}
export default Ember.Helper.helper(eq);
```

Working example: https://ember-twiddle.com/d4aaf5790e40b20ce492. You can change the emberjs version by clicking Dependencies -> Ember.js -> version. The code works with v2.0.2.

Let me know if this solution works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can implement the selectionChange:

HBS:

```
    <select class="left-float" onchange={{action "selectionchange" value="target.value"}} >   
    {{#each countries as |country|}}    
        <option value="{{country.code}}"  selected={{eq selectedCodecountry.code}}>
         {{country.name}}
     </option>  
    {{/each}} 
  </select>
```

Inside controller

```
 countries: [
         {code:"IN", name: "India"},
         {code: "US", name: "USA"},
         {code: "UK", name: "UK"}
       ],
       selectedCode: "US",
       actions: {
         selectionchange(code) {
           this.set('selectedCode', code);
         }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Can you share the code so that it will be easy to debug?

Comment: @ kavitha ,See this Demo http://plnkr.co/edit/5UBr3Trm5nX1NRfqHzZa?p=preview also look at the console for error

Comment: Iam getting  following errors at console a) Googling, I found that eq was removed from Ember 2.0, so there is an exception "helper named eq could not be found".
b) Also, the selectionChange is not getting triggered.